# Delete image in laravel through model relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, model

.Multiplae images are stored from another model but i can not delete the images one by one. messedup in eloquent. how to delete the image with this model relationship

This is my product model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title','image'];

    public function images(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\ProductImage');
    }
}
```

this is product image model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ProductImage extends Model
{
    public function product(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
}
```

This is view with delete link

```
@foreach($product->images as $image)
 <form class="product_image" action="{{ route('admin.product.image_delete',['id'=> $image->image]) }}" method="post">
@csrf
@method('DELETE')
    <img style="width:100%; height:100%;" src="{{ asset('upload/product/'.$image->image) }}">
        <button class="product_image_delete" type="submit">
           <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         </button>
 </form>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 //html file
@foreach($product->images as $image)
  <form class="product_image" action="{{ route('admin.product.image_delete',['id'=> 
  $image->id]) }}" method="post">
  @csrf
  @method('DELETE')
  <img style="width:100%; height:100%;" src="{{ 
asset('upload/product/'.$image->image) 
    }}">
    <button class="product_image_delete" type="submit">
       <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </button>
</form>
@endforeach
//in your controller for example:
     public function destroyAll($id){

   $photos=User::find($id)->photos;
   foreach($photos as $photo){
    $this->deleteImage($photo->name,'your_folder_name');
    $photo->delete();
}

     return back();

}
 
 
  protected function deleteImage($name,$folder){
  $image_path=public_path().'/'.$folder.'/'.$name;
  unlink($image_path);
 }
```

//you have just to change model name in your controller and add the function name in your route

Comment: Its working thanks a lot. i just messed in one thing in the delete view link i passed $image->image .this is the mistake i made